# Automatic array filling using GUI

Tags: c, arrays, user-interface

I am working with C and I have an array that I work on. The values being 0 or 1.

For the time being, since this array serves as the prerequisite for anything I do with my program, I am manually creating it from a file, where file contains the Row Column coordinates for starting and ending point and a vertical or horizontal line is filled with value 1 in the array.

I want only horizontal and vertical line for now. But I want to improve the efficiency of the whole array initialisation process.It is really tedious specifying the coordinates in a file. I want to have a GUI where each pixel corresponds to a cell of array and when I draw something in the window, the corresponding cell gets the value 1 in my array and once I have the array with me, I pass it to my C program.

Now, I can make use of some already existing software, or maybe some other quick fix for array initialisation, since my main program starts once the array has been initialised properly.

Thanks.

**Addition*

Operating System : Ubuntu.
Size OF Array For Now : 100*100 but that is because I am manually filling it up and I like to keep it small. But I dont see it extending beyond a normal computer screen, say a 1000*800

Comment: What operating system, what GUI library do you use? (On Linux, you may want to use Gtk if coding in *C*)? How large is your array?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did try to use GTK, but it seems that the documentation is not really good and there's a lot of new stuff to learn. I normally would not mind that, but I dont want to be spending a lot of time on this initialisation process. 
If I could somehow circumvent that. I understand it's not the best way, but I am working on pretty strict deadlines here.

Comment: You are kidding... The GTK documentation is quite nice.... (and you can also find books on GTK in libraries). And why is the initialization time such an issue for you? Filling a 1 megapixel pixmap is quite quick today. Did you benchmark it?

Comment: You could alo consider `cairo` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an image format.  Like TIFF, which does have a 1-bit variant which would be ideal for your case.  I suspect the image editing software known as GIMP can save 1-bit TIFFs, and even if not, you could create 8-bit ones and just count pixels as on or off based on some threshold.  There are plenty of libraries for dealing with TIFF, but you could also use BMP or something else if you want a simpler/dumber format (yet one that commodity software will help you edit).